# Не основной поток, rxjava2

Tags: rxjava2

Здравствуйте! У меня есть два класса, первый загружает страницу, через jsoup, второй выполняет с ней определённые действия и возвращает список. Первый класс вызывается из второго. В mainActivity, строю запрос ко второму классу при помощи rxjava2, но он вылетает из-за выполнения в основном потоке. Перелопатил массу страниц, перепробовал кучу вариантов, всё время одна и та же ошибка.

Ткните пожалуйста носом где почитать как правильно составить запрос для выполнения такого рода задач.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужны методы `subscribeOn` и `observeOn`. `subscribeOn` определяет на каком потоке будет выполнена подписка на rx-цепочку (указывается только 1 раз) и все последующие действия с данной цепочкой, если не переопределить это с помощью вызова `observeOn` (все последующие операции будут выполнены на указанном потоке, можно указывать несколько раз)
Т.е.

```
Observable.range(1, 10) //на io-треде
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map(x -> x * x) // на io-треде
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .map(x -> x + 20) // на computation
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(x ->
                editText.setText("Number: " + x) // на ui-потоке
        );
```